# How to bind jlabel with arraylist size?

Tags: swing, arraylist, jlabel

I am showing arraylist size in a JLabel. What I want is whenever the size of arraylist changes it should reflect in JLabel. Can it be done? Can I bind arraylist size to JLabel? I don't want to manually do this by `jLabel.setText(arrList.size());` every time.

Comment: You can't do that with ArrayList because this is not observable. You should take a look at JGoodies Binding `ObservableList` and its implementations, that could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no support in Java for binding a UI component to a data structure as you can in other languages like ActionScript. You could set up a timer that will ask the `ArrayList` how big it is and then set the text of the `JLabel` accordingly. You'd probably need to do this in a background thread as you wouldn't want to hold the main thread while your timer loops infinitely.

Comment: Actually I am doing `jLabel.setText(list.size());` whenever something adds or removes from the list. But want to know if it can be done automatically without calling `setText()`. Based on your answer I think its not possible.

Comment: @Harry Joy: Well the only way for you to set the text of a `JLabel` is using `setText`; there's no reason for you to avoid using it. What you really mean is that you don't want to have to remember to update the label whenever the list changes, right? For that I believe you'd need to create some sort of mechanism for keeping them in sync - one such being a timer that polls the list at a specified interval and updates the label with the size.

Comment: Yes I don't want to have to remember to update the label whenever the list changes because there are lots of places where list changes.Now let me try your solution.